# How to localise a CakePHP plugin?

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-1.3

I'm developing a CakePHP plugin which should support multiple languages. The procedure for i18n localisation is documented [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1228/Internationalization-Localization), but plugins aren't explicitly covered. Is this structure below supposed to work? Because it isn't for me at the moment, but I might be overlooking something.

```
/myapp/
  /plugins/
    /myplugin/
      /locale/
        default.pot
        /nld/
          /LC_MESSAGES/
            default.mo
            default.po
```

And calling the translation in the plugin controller like so:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'nld');
```

In my plugin views the localisation function is formatted like this:

```
__('MyPluginName', 'MyDefaultString')
```

Some of the posts on CakePHP and the localisation of plugins mention that all locales should go in to `/myapp/locale/`, instead of the plugin directory, but wouldn't that defy the purpose of the modular plugin structure? The entries I've read are from 2008 ([this one](http://groups.google.com/group/cakephp-edge/browse_thread/thread/cd91bea5f5edad84) for example), so I hope this isn't the case anymore.

Could anybody provide me with some more details on localising a Cake plugin, perhaps even a small step by step tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Plugin development tips and tricks](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/sky_l3ppard/2010/01/31/plugin-development-tips-and-tricks) article:

> Localization for plugins is handled
>   well and you can use it simply by
>   giving a plugin name for your po or mo
>   files.

Comment: Thanks! I followed the direction in that article and it still didn't work. Turns out I used the wrong language code, it should be "dut" instead of "nld". That's the one thing I didn't consider.

Comment: It may have not worked in the past as referenced here:

Ticket references :
http://code.google.com/p/lilblogs/source/browse/wiki/LocalizeHowTo.wiki?r=31
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/croogo/Dn8zqBu_1QU[1-25]